# R sum a list of matrix containing NaN

Tags: r

I have the following list of matrices one of with is a na matrix

```
l <- list(structure(c(-0.345207968896003,             -0.106294281751886,
 -0.106294281751886,   -0.0327278202985066),   .Dim  =   c(2L,   2L),
 .Dimnames    =    list(c("cst",     "HHI"),    c("cst",    "HHI"))),
 structure(c(1.15139745442976e-05,              3.68766982139475e-06,
 3.68766982139475e-06,  1.15176322872764e-06  ),  .Dim =  c(2L,  2L),
 .Dimnames    =    list(c("cst",     "HHI"),    c("cst",    "HHI"))),
 structure(c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
 c("cst",            "HHI"),            c("cst",            "HHI"))),
 structure(c(-7.27547318293674e-83,            -2.19548052580106e-83,
 -2.19548052580106e-83,  -7.02352060565763e-84 ),  .Dim =  c(2L, 2L),
 .Dimnames    =    list(c("cst",     "HHI"),    c("cst",    "HHI"))),
 structure(c(4.87470592316947e-170,            1.84511037510365e-170,
 1.84511037510365e-170,  6.6824969949533e-171), .Dim  =  c(2L, 2L  ),
 .Dimnames = list(c("cst",  "HHI"), c("cst", "HHI"))), structure(c(0,
 0,  0, 0),  .Dim  =  c(2L, 2L),  .Dimnames  = list(c("cst",  "HHI"),
 c("cst", "HHI"))))
```

and I would like to sum all the matrices using Reduce.

```
 a <-Reduce('+',l)
```

How can I sum the matrices removing the NaNs?

Comment: you can also define your own `+` operator to deal with this: `'%+%' <- function(x, y) if (any(!is.finite(y))) x else x + y` and use `Reduce('%+%',l)` instead. this assumes that `x is not NaN` but you could easily extend it to include the other cases, ie, `x is NaN` or `x and y are NaN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `replace` the `NA` values with `0` and use `Reduce`

```
Reduce(`+`,lapply(l, function(x) replace(x, which(is.na(x)), 0)))
#           cst         HHI
#cst -0.3451965 -0.10629059
#HHI -0.1062906 -0.03272667
```

Or if you need to remove the list element with all NAs

```
Reduce(`+`,l[!colSums(sapply(l, is.na))])
#           cst         HHI
#cst -0.3451965 -0.10629059
#HHI -0.1062906 -0.03272667
```

Or another option is `melt/acast`

```
library(reshape2)
acast(melt(l, na.rm=TRUE), Var1~Var2, value.var='value', sum)
#          cst         HHI
#cst -0.3451965 -0.10629059
#HHI -0.1062906 -0.03272667
```

Or we could convert it to `array` and get the `sum` or `rowSums` by specifying the `MARGIN` using `apply`

```
 apply(array(unlist(l), c(dim(l[[1]]), length(l)), 
      dimnames=c(dimnames(l[[1]]), NULL)), 1, rowSums, na.rm=TRUE)
 #          cst         HHI
 #cst -0.3451965 -0.10629059
 #HHI -0.1062906 -0.03272667

apply(array(unlist(l),c(dim(l[[1]]), length(l)),
      dimnames=c(dimnames(l[[1]]), NULL)), c(1,2), sum, na.rm=TRUE)
#         cst         HHI
#cst -0.3451965 -0.10629059
#HHI -0.1062906 -0.03272667
```